Who designed the USS Voyager in-universe?
I want to know who designed the USS Voyager. I want an in-universe. The ONLY clue that I know of to who designed the USS Voyager in-universe is the Doctor's quote, " Whoever designed this ship didn't think about crewmembers having to crawl around Jeffries tubes to get around" or something along those lines. I want to know who designed the USS Voyager specificly not who designed the Intrepid class.

That'd be starship designer extraordinaire Geoff Voyager.

Unless it differed markedly from the rest of the Intrepids, you want the class designer.

Something that big is designed by large teams of people, a Bureau of Ships organization.

To my knowledge, we're never given this information. We don't really know this about any starship; we know Leah Brahms worked on the design of the Galaxy-class engines, and that Ben Sisko led the team developing the Defiant, but I can't recall an example from anywhere in Trek where an individual is called out as "the designer" of a ship.
The closest you'll get is the ship's dedication plaque. This lists teams of people, not individual contributors, except for the single Chief of Staff, so there's no direct indication which name might represent Voyager's designer. However, the dedication plaques are essentially an in-joke populated with backstage staff credits, so even if the plaque had been clearly visible on screen it would be a bad idea to take it as fully in-setting canonical.
